# Fetch elements first character from a list

Tags: typescript

This is the list.

```
[  
    {"name":"Ram", "email":"Ram@gmail.com"},  
    {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com"}  
]
```

Need to get the first letter of name object in a different array like below

```
   [  
         {"name":"R"},  
         {"name":"B"}  
     ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map` to achieve this.

```js
const randomArray = [  
    {"name":"Ram", "email":"Ram@gmail.com"},  
    {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com"}  
]  

const newArray = randomArray.map(user => { return { name: user.name.charAt(0) } });

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map()` on your array.

```
const newArray = originalArray.map(user => {
  return {name: user.name.charAt(0)};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `map` [[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map)] to achieve what you want :

```js
let array = [  
    {"name":"Ram", "email":"Ram@gmail.com"},  
    {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com"}  
];

let new_array = array.map((object) => { return { name : object.name[0] } });

console.log(new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the above array with a function or the map method.

```
let newArr = oldArr.map(el => {
       let newName = el.name.charAt(0)
       return el = {name: newName}       
})

function updateArr(oldArr){
   let result = []
   for(let i = 0; i < oldArr.length; i++) {
      let newName = oldArr[i].name.charAt(0)
      result.push({name: newName})
   }
   return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let a =[  
    {"name":"Ram", "email":"Ram@gmail.com"},  
    {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com"}  
];
let b = [];
a.forEach(element => {
    b.push({'name': element['name'].charAt(0)});
})
```

[image]